# Issue with endless loop in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Working in Android Studio and I've run into a few small issues so I figured I would ask for help / advice.

I am currently working on a small testing application that would allow users to open the application and select practice test or timed test (as displayed in picture 1). If users select practice test they have unlimited time to select an answer and the systems tells them if they have picked the correct answer. If the user selects timed than the system allots a predetermined amount of time and after each question the score is added and calculated, here lies my issues.

1.) Right now my code loops endlessly, ideally (at least for the timed aspect) I want my code to go through the 5 questions scoring the correct or incorrect based on the users selection. Then I want to display the # correct and in correct.

So my question is two fold, first how do I go about preventing my code from looping endless so I can begin to record iterations as ++correctAnswer ++incorrect answer. And, when it comes time to display the results, should I create a new activity to display the results.

Android is a bit confusing to me, I hope I have provided enough information and I appreciate and helping advice.

Thank You

** Code **

```
private int currentQuestion;
private String[] questions;
private String[] answers;
private Button answerButton;
private Button questionButton;
private TextView questionView;
private TextView answerView;
private EditText answerText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}



public void init()
{
    questions = new String[]{"What is the acronym for Computer Science and Information Management?",
    "What is the CSIT corse number of the class you are currently in?",
    "What Android program do we use to create android applications?"};
    answers = new String[]{"CSIT","2250", "Android Studio"};
    currentQuestion = -1;
    answerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);
    questionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuestionButton);
    questionView = (TextView)
            findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
    answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerTextView);
    answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);
    answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer();
        }});

    questionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showQuestion();
        }});
}


// Display current quesiton
public void showQuestion()
{
    currentQuestion++;
    if(currentQuestion == questions.length)
        currentQuestion =0;

    questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
    answerView.setText("");
    answerText.setText("");

}

// Return true if answer is correct
public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
{
    return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion]));
}

// Display correct or incorrec results
public void checkAnswer()
{
    String answer = answerText.getText().toString();
    if(isCorrect(answer))
        answerView.setText("You are correct!");
    else
        answerView.setText("Sorry, the correct answer is "+answers[currentQuestion]);

}}
```

[image: Home Screen]
Home Screen

[image]
Quiz Screen

Comment: Where is the loop ? i can't fine any.

Comment: I was confused at first. There is no loop, the process continues as you press the buttons.

Comment: Sorry was working on this, I was under the impression "        if(currentQuestion == questions.length)" was apart of that and I needed to add something like if (currentQuestion > 5) finish(); - or do some other action, is this incorrect thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a condition check if `currentQuestion == 5` at the end of `checkAnswer()`. If so proceed to the results screen